# rewrite / restrict specific domain name in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond, restrictions

We have `https://example1.com/login` and `example2.com/login` being hosted from the same apache server (2.2.22). I want to restrict `/login` on `example1.com`.

- `example1.com/login` --> 404 (preferably) or 403
- `example2.com/login` --> login page

I tried

```
<Location /login>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from example1.com
Allow from example2.com
</Location>
```

It disables `/login` from both `example1.com` and `example2.com`. Can I restrict just `example1.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using mod_rewrite which allows you to check the *host* through which the site is being accessed. Try the following, in your server config (or `<Directory>` section or `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?login$ - [R=404,L]
```

The above serves a 404 Not Found if you request `example1.com/login`, but will not do anything if you request `example2.com/login` (the request will simply be allowed through).

The `=` prefix on the `RewriteCond` *CondPattern* makes it an exact lexicographical comparison, not a regex, so no need to escape the dot or use *anchors*.

In order to serve a 403 Forbidden instead you can change the flags on the `RewriteRule`, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?login$ - [F]
```

---

> ```
> <Location /login>
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from example1.com
> Allow from example2.com
> </Location>
> ```
>
> It disables `/login` from both `example1.com` and `example2.com`.

I'm rather curious... this would seemingly *allow* all access, not deny it? The `Deny from ...` directive denies access to the user from `example1.com` (via reverse DNS lookup on the remote IP address), not the user who is accessing the `example1.com` host. Neither the `Deny` or `Allow` directives should match so it should default *Allow*. (?)

---

> ...how do i add multiple rewrite conditions for the same RewriteCond?

**UPDATE:** Note that `RewriteCond` directives (ie. *conditions*) apply to the single `RewriteRule` directive that follows. Continuing the above example, if you wish to block several URLS (eg. `/login`, `/demo` and `/test`) for `example1.com` only then you can either combine all these in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(login|demo|test)$ - [R=404,L]
```

This is OK in this instance since the URLs are limited and all very short. Alternatively, you can create a condition for each URL and use the `OR` flag. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

This states... for all URLs where the `HTTP_HOST` is `example1.com` *and* the URL is either `/login` *or* `/demo` *or* `/test` then serve the 404 error document. However, the first example (using the `RewriteRule` *pattern*) would be more efficient, since this is what's processed first.

Comment: Thanks.. i'm able to work with the RewriteCond and RewriteRule combination..
one followup question..
how do i add multiple rewrite conditions for the same RewriteCond?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?login$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^/?demo$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^/?test$ - [R=404,L]

the second and third RewriteRule is applied for for example2.com too(along with example1). 
 
You were right about the 'Deny from example1.com Allow from example2.com ' my configuration ALLOWED from both example1 and example2.

Comment: `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the _single_ `RewriteRule` directive that follows - however, you can still do what you require. I've updated my answer.

Comment: **Perfect** works like a charm. Thanks for your help